How to create a temporary view on top csv file
How to create a temporary view on top csv file. Iam performing this view creation in Azure Data bricks.help me how create view and read the data.
my data looks like:
Delimeter: ~
"1"~"test"~"123"~"dasa"~"east"
"2"~"test"~"123"~"dasa"~"east"
i want to load this data into proper table format.

Did you try using spark.read.option("sep", "~") on the data and then apply createOrReplaceTempView on the dataframe that is getting created?

Here is my sample CSV file data:
ID~position~number~stage~direction "1"~"test"~"123"~"dasa"~"east" "2"~"test"~"123"~"dasa"~"east"

In the above data, ~ is the column delimiter and ' '(space) is the row delimiter. So mention those delimiters while reading the CSV file as in the below code:
df = spark.read \
    .format("csv") \
    .option("delimiter", "~") \
    .option("linesep", " ") \
    .option("header", "true") \
    .load("<csvfileParh>")

Create a temp_view using the below code:
df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_view")

Query the temp view using the below code:
result = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM temp_view")
result.show()

You will get the output below:

Here is the complete code for your reference:
df = spark.read \
    .format("csv") \
    .option("delimiter", "~") \
    .option("linesep", " ") \
    .option("header", "true") \
    .load("<csvfilePath>")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_view")
result = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM temp_view")
result.show()

